# Reading the first two bytes from a file efficiently - Golang

Tags: file, go

I'm trying to find a good way of reading the first two bytes from a file using Go.

I have some `.zip` files in my current directory, mixed in with other files.

I would like to loop through all the files in the directory and check if the first two bytes contain the right `.zip` identifier, namely `50 4B`.

What would be a good way to accomplish this using the standard library without having to read the entire file?

Going through the available functions in the `io` package I managed to find:

```
func LimitReader(r Reader, n int64) Reader
```

Which seems to fit my description, it reads from `Reader` (How do I get a `Reader`?) but stops after `n` bytes. Since I'm rather new to Go, I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: os.File which you obtain with os.Open("path") IS a Reader

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the initial reader by opening the file. For 2 bytes, I wouldn't use the `LimitReader` though. Just reading 2 bytes with [io.ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) is easier.

```
r, err := os.Open(file)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

defer r.Close()

var header [2]byte
n, err := io.ReadFull(r, header[:])
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```